# SD card error: can't read superblock

Tags: mount, sd-card

I am currently running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I inserted my SD card in a DSLR using an SD adapter but later on, when I inserted it to my phone, it does not show my SD card, later on I inserted the SD card in my PC (which is running Ubuntu), it's showing:

```
error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/dev0101/[id]_[DEV] : can't read superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

So I tried to search for the problems and I got to know that my sd card shows this:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1 contains a vfat file system labelled '[id]__[DEV]'
```

So I need to fix the problem as fast as possible.
Also to mention I checked my sd card is working in an old Nokia keypad phone where I saw that many files have been deleted.

Comment: Did you run fsck or another repair tool on the file system? Have you made sure this is indeed a valid VFATfile system? (See https://www.tecmint.com/find-linux-filesystem-type/ for hints on how to do that.) Did you try to mount the file system with the "-t vfat" switch added to the mount command? (Hint: "man fstab" will give you a list of possible file systems.)

Comment: I did run the fsck command in terminal and in the last line, it showed something that identified it as vfat...